# override CSS style or add to it?

Tags: html, css, overriding

I have a template that has a lot of CSS formatting, but now when I try to add my text I cannot add any formatting to it. Within a paragraph, I try to put superscripts, italics, but nothing works. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little explaination about overiding CSS

I'll take for my example this simple HTML :

```
<div id='home' class='current'></div>
```

If you have, for example, a css like

```
#home{color : blue;}
.current{color : orange;}
```

The text will be blue since #home is "stronger"

If we put values to selector: id=10 class=5 node selector (div) = 1

so #home = 10 and is higher than .current wich equal 5, #homestyles will override.

you could use li.current but again, 5+1=6 wich is lower than an id.

But #home.current will equal 15! Wich will overide #home styles!

But if your color style is on the node itself within the attribute style="" you have to remove it with jquery or use !important :

```
.current{
    color: blue !important;
}
```

It will override EVERY css but it is not recommended.

Note that the value i am using are not the exact one, so `.parentClass .class` will maybe not over an id and i can't find the original values... But keep in mind that the more selective you are, the more chance you have to override a style.

At last, if you have 2 selector with the same value, the last one called will be the one overriding.

Use chrome inspector or firebug to see what's overriding what.

Comment: I found that <i><em> where not included in my CSS style sheet. I added and that solved the problem.